# Making sense of Weapon Modifications in SWEOTE?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars, german

There is a thing in [Star Wars Edge of the Empire](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/star-wars-edge-of-the-empire/) with regard to weapon modifications (Chapter 5: Equipment)* that I just don't get:

It states that if you get a Despair symbol, the equipment is destroyed: Except that you only can get a Despair symbol through a [Red Challenge Die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Roleplaying_Game_(Fantasy_Flight_Games)#The_Custom_Dice), but modification difficulty is only *increased*, i.e. Purple dice are added and I cannot find any mention of *upgrading* the difficulty to even include a Red Die. What kind of sense does that make?

* Note that I only have the German rulebook, so the translation in the German rule book may be inaccurate, but it doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: You were correct with the English terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GM is allowed to use a **Destiny Point** to upgrade the difficult of any check, regardless of the situation.
That way you can get at least one *challenge dice* on your check.

Also note that some specific weapons also upgrade the difficult on this check, while others will add *setback die* to the check.

**Critical Injuries**

A character that recieves a critical injury might have his difficulty dice upgraded, such as the *Blinded* condition:

> **Blinded**: The target can no longer see Upgrade the difficulty of all checks twice. Upgrade the difficulty of Perception and Vigilance checks three times.

Keep in mind that simple checks will hardly, ever, use a *challenge dice*, those are reserved for situations and enemies to will put your action at risk.
That rule is there merely to cover a situation where the GM may want to increase the risk of something really bad happening, which is the purpose of the destiny point upgrade.

Note also that pretty much all skills mentions what happens if you roll a despair, but few of them actually have rules that specify how you will obtain a challenge die on that check (knowledge skills, for example).

If you are a professional mechanic, this should hardly ever happen, the most that can happen is that you fail to attach it, which might be caused by lack of ability, proficiency, or setbacks that got into your way.

Comment: Can you give an example of a specific weapon? Anything in the base book?

Comment: None on the core book. It should be either on the smuggler or hired gun books.

Comment: Added a note about the *Blinded* critical injury.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the book makes no mention in chapter 5 about upgrading from Difficulty to Challenge dice for the installation of a modification, so it would appear at first that the rule makes no sense.  However, you must remember that the GM can add situational upgrades at any time to any roll.

For example, if you had a modification in hand, and are jumped by a squad of Stormtroopers, and were attempting to install it *in combat*, the GM could rightfully upgrade the Difficulty dice to Challenge dice.  It should be noted that the only time you should attempt such outlandish actions - like installing a mod in the field under fire - a force token should have been flipped.  This is really where upgrading and downgrading comes into play in the three FFG Star Wars games.  That should go without saying, but it is the Internet.

GMs are encouraged throughout the book, and its two sister core books, to upgrade difficulty and apply setback dice, and to balance this by offering boost dice.

Comment: Cheers. The infobox in chapter 1 seems to say though that "upgrading/downgrading are normally only used when the rules state so explicitly" (paraphrased from german). Well, I guess an experienced GM can decide better whether to add black dice or whether to upgrade the difficulty.

Comment: Also the Force pool.

Comment: @Martin It later mentions that upgrading and downgrading should happen when the force pool is invoked - I updated to be more clear on that matter.